# Links move from left to center of AppBar when screen is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this `AppBar`:

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    <Link to="/">
      <IconButton aria-label="Home" style={isActive(history, "/")}>
        <HomeIcon/>
      </IconButton>
    </Link>
    {
    !auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: -12 }}>
        <Link to="/signin">
          <Button style={isActive(history, "/signin")}>Sign In
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </span>)
    }
    {
      auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span>
        <Link to="/issues">
          <Button style={isActive(history, "/issues")}>Issues
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/users">
          <Button style={isActive(history, "/users")}>Users
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/signup">
          <Button style={isActive(history, "/signup")}>Create User
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </span>)
    }
    {
      auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span  style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: -12 }}>
        <Link to={"/user/" + auth.isAuthenticated().user._id}>
          <IconButton aria-label="MyProfile" style={isActive(history, "/user/" + auth.isAuthenticated().user._id)}>
            <AccountCircle/>
          </IconButton>
        </Link>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => {
            auth.signout(() => history.push('/'))
          }}>Sign Out</Button>
      </span>)
    }
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

When I'm not signed in, everything appears as it should. The `Home` icon is to the left and `Sign In` is to the right:

[image]

If I then login, everything appears as expected. The `Home` icon, `Issues`, `Users` and `Create User` links all appear to the left and the `My profile` icon and `Log out` link appear to the right:

[image]

It remains like this even if I click between the different links. However, if I refersh my page by clicking the refresh button in the browser or press F5, the `Issues`, `Users` and `Create User` links all move to the center:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like it may have something to do with that second `auth.isAuthenticated()` test. It doesn't seem to be checking anything that the first isn't and it's returning that `marginLeft: auto`.

Comment: Yes. I want the contents of both to only display if there is authentication but I want those in the first to display to the left and the second to display to the right.